# Office 2013 - Paste Special Shows 'Unformatted Unicode Text' only - Show Options Turned on in Advanced Options

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, unicode, paste

About two weeks ago my "Paste Special" stopped working in Office 2013 products.

Before, I could paste and choose how I wanted it to work.

But, since, all I have in the Paste Special options is 'Unformatted Unicode Text'.

In Word 2013, under File>Options>Advanced, all the 'normal' options are chosen, most are 'Keep Source Formatting (Default)', and the 'Show Paster Options button when content is pasted' box is checked.  But, it doesn't work.  All I get is plain text, I lose pictures and formatting.

Same in Excel.  I have changed options, closed out, even rebooted, but nothing fixes it.

Comment: If you right-click Paste Special, you don't get the different past options?

Comment: Have you tried the option to repair Office? (in COntrol Panel, depends on which version of Windows).